# Make Si4703 evaluation board Bluetooth capable

Tags: serial, i2c, bluetooth, frequency-modulation

While looking for a Bluetooth RDS-TMC receiver which could be queried with FOSS software, and after realizing there’s probably not too much on the market, I stumbled across [Si4703 evaluation boards](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12938) for use with single-board computers.

I have successfully used a Si4703-based USB dongle to pick up RDS-TMC messages on Linux, thus the evaluation boards looked like a good starting point—Linux has drivers for it (which will probably need some tweaking, but I’m hoping to reuse the bulk of it), and there’s an application ([RDS Surveyor)](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/RdsSurveyor) which can query and parse TMC data from the chip. Analog audio isn’t really a concern—I don’t need it for my purposes.

<del>Is there a way to convert the signals from the Si470x board to serial and hook it up to a Bluetooth-to-serial adapter? Or any other way to get the device to “speak” Bluetooth?</del>

Looking around a bit, the chip seems to speak I²C, with the pins exposed directly through the evaluation board. I’m not familiar with the details of I²C but, to my knowledge, generic Bluetooth adapters exist.

Besides the `SDIO` and `SDCLK` pins, the board also has a `RST_n` pin. Initializing the device involves some bit banging:

- Set `SDIO` and `RST_n` to low
- Wait a bit
- Set `RST_n` to high again
- Wait a bit
- Start using the device

Is this compatible with standard I²C, i.e. would a Bluetooth-to-I²C bridge be capable of initializing this device in the same way described above?

Comment: Ask Silicon Laboratories. It's their part.

Comment: Looking at the programming guide (http://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN230.pdf#page=7), I see that there’s a second bus selection mode, which is done by setting both `GPIO1` and `GPIO3` to high when `RST_n` is set to high (i.e. on powerup). That takes precedence over the selection mode described above. Guess I’ll get the module and do a dry run with a Pi to see if this works as expected.